# Magento sessions

Tags: magento

Can anyone tell me how magento create sessions???
I have magento with 600 users per day, sessions/coockie TTL is 1 week. 60% of this users is comeback everyday users.
Sessions dir have 285580 session files. All files have dates no more than 1 week.

So from where we have so much session files with 600 users?

Answer (score 0):

Just a theory, poorly behaved bots are crawling your site (ie without persistent cookies) and Magento is creating a new session for every page view.

Compare your apache logs with your session files to confirm, then ban the offending bots in your /robots.txt file.

Comment: already looked by magento logs (no apache) - no bots and no scanning ip's - it's real clients data as I can see

Comment: I see this on my own magento site, lots of little session file "turds" from one-page visits, usually clustered together in a small time span.  bots.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/265668/#t359093

Comment: Cleaning is by server - I trying to understand why this happened

Answer (score 0):

The Sessions are PHP sessions, not specifically Magento.

You've got a few options here:

1. use some kind of proxy for your server like Cloudflare (https://www.cloudflare.com/), that this has DDoS protection, so if the problem is malicious, this will provide some kind of protection against that.
2. Go through your apache log files and identify the source of the traffic, depending on your distro of linux, that'll be somewhere like /var/log/httpd/access_log.

I use something like this to get the last 20 lines, but you make need a grep if you can't find it.

```
    $ tail /var/log/httpd/access_log -n20
```

Then setup a robots.txt to restrict bots, or a firewall rule to block malicious traffic.

3. Magento allows (and encourages) the use of Redis for session and cache Management. The following local.xml example has 10.0.0.2 as your db server, and 10.0.0.3 as your redis server.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!--
   /**
    * Magento
    *
    * NOTICE OF LICENSE
    *
    * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
    * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
    * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
    * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
    * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
    * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
    * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
    *
    * DISCLAIMER
    *
    * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to         newer
    * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
    * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more         information.
    *
    * @category   Mage
    * @package    Mage_Core
    * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien         (http://www.varien.com)
    * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free         License (AFL 3.0)
    */
   -->
   <config>
       <global>
           <install>
               <date><![CDATA[Wed, 18 Jan 2012 06:19:25 +0000]]></date>
           </install>
           <crypt>
               <key><![CDATA[{some crypt key}]]></key>
           </crypt>
           <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
           <resources>
               <db>
                   <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
               </db>
               <default_setup>
                   <connection>
                       <host><![CDATA[10.0.0.2]]></host>
                       <username><![CDATA[dbusername]]></username>
                       <password><![CDATA[dbpassword]]></password>
                       <dbname><![CDATA[dbschema]]></dbname>
                       <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                       <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                       <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                       <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                       <active>1</active>
                   </connection>
               </default_setup>
           </resources>
           <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
           <redis_session>
               <host>10.0.0.3</host>
               <port>6379</port>
               <password>redispassword</password>
               <timeout>2.5</timeout>
               <persistent></persistent>
               <db>2</db>
               <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>
               <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
               <log_level>1</log_level>
               <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>
               <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>
               <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
               <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>
           </redis_session>   
       <cache>
           <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
           <backend_options>
               <server>10.0.0.3</server>
               <port>6379</port>
               <persistent></persistent>
               <database>1</database>
               <password>redispassword</password>
               <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
               <connect_retries>3</connect_retries>    
               <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>      
               <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> 
               <compress_data>1</compress_data> 
               <compress_tags>1</compress_tags> 
               <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
               <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
               <use_lua>0</use_lua>
           </backend_options>
       </cache>    
   </global>
       <admin>
           <routers>
               <adminhtml>
                   <args>
                       <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                   </args>
               </adminhtml>
           </routers>
       </admin>
   </config>
   ```

Other than that, you can always look at your session timeouts, seeing they're all under a week old, it seems like there's some session cleaning going on, but as to why there are so many sessions, it could be anything from a poorly setup load balancer (which would see session / cart problems at the customer end), or something like timeout problems with PHP.